# How to only return String objects from JdbcTemplate queryForList?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

By default, `queryForList()` returns each for as a `Map<String, Object>`. The object can be plain `String`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, etc.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, params);
```

Question: how can I enfore returning any values as `String.class`? So I'd be having a `Map<String, String>`.

I tried: `jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, params, Map<String, String>.class)`
But that statement seems to be invalid and does not compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917906/return-type-for-jdbctemplate-queryforlistsql-object-classtype

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` internally uses `JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(ResultSet, int)` to extract values from the resultSet. It is type sensitive and so maps the SQL types to Java types. You could either cast all columns to varchar in your SQL select statement or use a custom RowMapper as @membersound suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but the following works:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new ColumnMapRowMapper() {
    @Override
    protected Object getColumnValue(ResultSet rs, int index) {
       return rs.getString(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I print that? And what will be the result?

Comment: The result is returned from the method `jdbcTemplate.query`, and you can process it of course however you want.