# Jdbc returns empty list but SQL query succesfully gets data [Spring]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute this query:

```
@Override
public UserInfo get(Long id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ";
    List<UserInfo> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new UserInfoMapper(),id);
    return list.get(0);
}
```

but jdbc return empty list and I get exception at return line. 
But if try to execute directly though the console it returns:
[Query,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm0hO.png) [Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmv4c.png)

Query was executed with id 1 and retured correct anwser;
But in method its returned [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzZa0.png)

I couldn't find any same questions so that may be point at my inattention to something. But I can't see any problem that may cause this. Thanks in advance;

**Updated 1**
Changing code to

```
@Override
public UserInfo get(Long id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ";
    List<UserInfo> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] {id},new UserInfoMapper());
    return list.get(0);
}
```

resulted in same: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhttD.png)
Updated 2

```
@Override
public UserInfo mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
    info.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
    info.setFirstname(resultSet.getString("firstname"));
    info.setMiddlename(resultSet.getString("middlename"));
    info.setLastname(resultSet.getString("lastname"));
    info.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
    info.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
    info.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
    info.setMobilephone(resultSet.getString("mobilephone"));
    info.setPosition(resultSet.getString("position"));
    return info;
}
public class UserInfo {
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String middlename;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String mobilephone;
    private String position;

    public UserInfo() {
    }
}
```

Getter and setters for each field is there but I think there is no need to show them up.

Comment: change code as follows jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new Object{id});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Type for jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, object, classType)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917906/return-type-for-jdbctemplate-queryforlistsql-object-classtype)

Comment: If u meant to do like this: 
List<UserInfo> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,id,new UserInfoMapper()); it won't work :(

Comment: Mapper would be the last param

Comment: Show `UserInfoMapper` and `UserInfo` please.

Comment: Last thing, do you have multiple DB ? Are you sure you are running the query on the correct DB ?

Comment: In Spring config method getDataSource I specifed schema:
        dataSource.setSchema("airline"); Is that enough to be sure that queries are executed on airline.users?

Comment: no suggestions? :c

Comment: I see this is a 2 year old question, however in the odd chance that you still remember the solution - did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I used Hibernate :)

Answer (score 1):

Check user credentials that you are using to connect database from your application and the user credentials in console. And also check owner schema , table owner schema in your application.